# Changing my Gmail address

Tags: gmail

How do I change my Gmail address without messing too many things up?

I want to stop someone from harassing me through email.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "messing too many things up."  Are you talking about the other Google services you have participated in?  Parenthetically, you can block the sender and all of their emails will go to Spam.

Answer (score 5):

You could [Block that sender](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) if you wished.  Unless they are creating multiple accounts.  If you really want to create a new one, you can create a new account and forward the old one for a short term until you believe you made everyone aware of the change. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158?hl=en